# R graph error: prettyDate range too small for 'min.n'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame and I want to plot some data and highlight the points on the graph

```
time<- as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-10 20:56:53","2014-12-10 20:56:53"), tz= "GMT")
p<-c(49.32, 60)
s<-c("B","")
pointcolor<-c("Green","")
share<-c(35,0)
pointsize<-c(1,0)
shapeType<-c(16,10)
bigDF<-data.frame(time=time, p=p, s=s, pointcolor=pointcolor, share=share, pointsize=pointsize, shapeType=shapeType)
bigDF
```

the data frame looks like

```
                 time     p s pointcolor share pointsize shapeType
1 2014-12-10 20:56:53 49.32 B      Green    35         1        16
2 2014-12-10 20:56:53 60.00                  0         0        10
```

now I want to plot the points as  a line and highlight the first point with a green dot of size 1 and shapetype of 16.

I call plot

```
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType), size = pointsize, color = pointsize))
```

and i get this error:

> Error in prettyDate(x = x, n = n, min.n = min.n, sep = sep, ...) : 
>     range too small for 'min.n'

any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a factor to `shape` parameter.

```
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType), size = pointsize, color = pointsize))
```

Comment: Thank you I changed the code but now I get an error:  Error in prettyDate(x = x, n = n, min.n = min.n, sep = sep, ...) : 
  range too small for 'min.n'

Comment: @user3022875 this is due to your example. Increase the time difference between two points (a few seconds should work).

Comment: This helped me. Weird that it is not accepted. I do think it is more like a bug than a feature though.